# How can I save asp generated page in html archive?

Tags: html, asp-classic

I want to save the result of processing an ASP page as html file. Anyone knows if is that possible? Thanks

Comment: All ASP pages are finally rendered as HTML. So you can do it very well!

Comment: ok thnaks, but I want to save it on the server, can you help me?

Comment: In asp.net we can use WebRequest object and get response and save it. As i have not worked on ASP i have no idea. But it should be possible, all we need to do is make a request in server side code and process the Response, which is HTML

Comment: You can use XMLHTTP to scrape your pages and then FSO to save them instead with the .htm extension.  If you are trying to save the sites for performance, IIS takes care of caching for you, and its not really necessary.  If you want to move them to a server that does not support asp, then you can use a program like HTTPTRACK to copy your whole website, (changes extensions to html)

Answer (score 1):

This can help you save the output of the ASP Page

```
<script runat="server">
void Page_Load() {
  String inputFile = MapPath("input-page.aspx");
  String sDiskFile = "result.htm";

  WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(inputFile);

  WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
  Stream stream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();

  StreamReader oReader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.ASCII);

  StreamWriter oWriter = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath(sDiskFile));
  oWriter.Write(oReader.ReadToEnd());

  oWriter.Close();
  oReader.Close();
  webResponse.Close();

  // display confirmation that it worked
  lblOutput.Text = inputFile;
  aLink.Text = sDiskFile;
  aLink.NavigateUrl = sDiskFile;

}
//-----------------------------------------
</script>
```